# XPath question multiple selects

Tags: xpath

```
var assets1 = data.SelectNodes("//asset[@id]=" + oldBinaryAssetId);
var assets2 = data.SelectNodes("//Asset[@id]=" + oldBinaryAssetId);
```

Is it possible to make 1 xpath query of the two above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your XPath is wrong to be gin with. You probably mean:

```
data.SelectNodes("//Asset[@id = '" + oldBinaryAssetId + "']");
```

To combine both variants (upper- and lower-case), you could use:

```
data.SelectNodes("//*[(name() = 'Asset' or name() = 'asset') and @id = '" + oldBinaryAssetId + "']");
```

or

```
data.SelectNodes("(//Asset | //asset)[@id = '" + oldBinaryAssetId + "']");
```

If you have any way to avoid the  `//` operator, I recommend doing so. Your queries will be faster when you do, though this might only be noticable with large input documents.

Comment: Yes, indeed, sorry for the mistake. Thx.